# How to compare file differences between 2 virtualbox snapshots?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

How to compare file differences between 2 virtualbox snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

You could [mount both virtual drives](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4748) and compare them using a diff tool.

Comment: Thread mentions "It works only on fix sized VDI-files, without having any snapshots!", unfortunately it is not possible to do using ImDisk

Comment: *Caution never tried:*  Clone the drive twice and collapse each snapshot down, then you should be able to mount them.